# Conditional Column POLL: SQL vs Power Query vs DAX

Tags: sql, excel, powerbi, dax, powerquery

Need to add a multi conditional (approx 12) column to an Excel file and was wondering what was more efficient: **SQL** (CASE), **M/PowerQuery** (if-then-else), or **DAX** (SWITCH).

What are you experiences?

TIA,
Danny

Comment: You need to explain your context better. How would you even use SQL inside of Excel or DAX outside of a pivot table?

Comment: Sorry... I'm importing data from SQL server to data model and was wondering if it would be better to add conditional column using 1) SQL query/view (before import) or 2) PowerQuery editor (before loading to data model) or 3) DAX column in data model... make sense?

Comment: (thanks @AlexisOlson for reply)

Comment: I don't think there is a definitive answer to be had here. It depends on quite a number of factors: what kind of role you have on the server, workflow standards you might adhere to, maintainability / documentation, server performance vs. CPU performance, etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @AlexisOlson, so many variables! :-) Thanks again for your response. I'll stick to what I know best...

Answer (score 0):

I would use the **Conditional Column** feature in the Query Editor ("M/PowerQuery") for this requirement.  It's the only option where you won't need to write any code at all, even for requirements like "does not contain" that are quite complex to code in your alternatives.

I tell my data analyst clients not to bother learning SQL any more - the Power BI Query Editor / Power Query for Excel is so much more productive.